# Android L 5.0.1 wont unlink my exchange account from GMail

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I updated my Nexus 5  to L5.0.1. No problems except my Outlook exchange account is now linked to GMail which I really do not want. There seems to be no way to unlink it either despite deleting the exchange account!

In the Help section it says Goto Settings/Accounts and look under POP3 or IMAP but neither of these are visible.

Any suggestions??

Comment: What do you mean the exchange account is "linked" to Gmail?  Do you mean messages your messages show up in Gmail app?

Comment: @Chahk When you upgrade to Lollipop, you get a new gmail app.  All your e-mail accounts are linked to that one app.  That's what they're saying.  It's all explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the new Android 5.0 update, GMail was made to be available as the only e-mail app you would need.  Instead of having to have 2 different email apps for gmail and exchange, it would do everything for you.  Now remember, your exchange email is completely separate from your gmail, so there is nothing happening to your e-mail, it's not being hijacked by Google or anything, the app is just a place where it is getting delivered.  If you still don't want them in the same app, then you can always install a different email app to handle your exchange e-mail.

Download an e-mail app, such as [Nine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3&hl=en) that will handle your exchange e-mail in a separate app.  First you are going to have to delete the exchange e-mail from your GMail app, then install the new email application, then add it to the new application.